# Angular UI-router: ok to leave first child empty? Or hidden?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to have a nested view with UI router, which I've done before (see image) with a main section and then a nav which loads sub-sections into the nested UI-View.  This I can do, no issues.

[image]

My question is: this time I need to have the initial child state not show to the user until a button is clicked, like this:

[image]

Can I do this?  Or is it better to load the "baseball" view but hide it and the nav with `ng-hide`?

**UPDATE**

Someone asked how I would do the simple nested states in a case like this:

```
    (function() {

  'use strict';

  angular.module('elements').config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('elements', {
      url: '/elements',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'modules/elements/templates/elements.html',
      controller: 'ElementsController as elements'
    })

    .state('elements.buttons', {
      url: '/elements/buttons',
      templateUrl: 'modules/elements/templates/elements-buttons.html'
    })

    .state('elements.accordion', {
      url: '/elements/accordion',
      templateUrl: 'modules/elements/templates/elements-accordion.html',
      controller: 'AccordionController as accordion'
    })

    .state('elements.colorcharts', {
      url: '/elements/colorcharts',
      templateUrl: 'modules/elements/templates/elements-colors-charts.html',
      controller: 'ChartColorsController as charts'
    })

    .state('elements.grid', {
      url: '/elements/grid',
      templateUrl: 'modules/elements/templates/elements-grid.html'
    });

  });

})();
```

Comment: You might need to explain your issue a bit more.  yes, it is possible to have child states that are only included on the page in some conditions, but it would be helpful to see the way you currently have your states defined.

Comment: I haven't defined them yet, I am trying to decide if this strategy is worth it or do it a different way. I amended the question to show how I'd do it now.

Comment: which state in your example is the one that you want to be hidden?

Comment: what would be helpful is seeing what is defined in the template for `elements.html`.

Comment: The first, "buttons"

Comment: on the main page is a title (i.e. "Elements"), a left nav containing the child states as links, and a ui-view to display the child states.

Comment: so then you can only view one state at a time; is your question, then, how to have a state where no child states are visible? you could make your base state not abstract in that case....

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is absolutely possible. I usually accomplish this by using programmatically defined states, which looks like it should work for your situation.

If you have a state for baseball then you could control it as such:

state config

```
.state('baseball', {
  url: '/views/baseball',
  template: 'imabaseball!'
})
```

html

```
<div ui-view="{{state}}">
<button ng-click="state = 'baseball'">Show Baseball</button>
```

Then the view in question would not be rendered until the user clicked the button